# How can I get all completed tasks to clear on function invocation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working in Angular, and I have checkboxes that switch the Boolean (to signify task completion). I also have two arrays, one that holds a list of objects and another to hold the first key values once completed and cleared.

```
$scope.taskList = [{
  complete: false,
  foo: "1",
  bar: "2",
  baz: "3"
}];

$scope.completedTasks = [];
```

The below function works properly to clear tasks when only one or two are checked; however, when the number of items checked grows, only a portion of checked items will clear; if you keep invoking the function, eventually all tasks will clear, but I can't figure out how to clear the entire list in one fell swoop.

```
$scope.clearComplete = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.taskList.length; i++) {
    if ($scope.taskList[i].complete == true) {
      $scope.completedTasks.push($scope.taskList[i].foo);
      $scope.taskList.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  console.log($scope.completedTasks);
  return $scope.taskList;
};
```

I'm at a loss for how to correct the logic and am hoping that some fresh eyes will be able to help me out.

For this project, I'm trying to keep dependencies low, without the help of other helper libraries like Underscore and Lodash.

Comment: You shouldn't modify `taskList` while iterating it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any external libraries to use `forEach`, or `filter`. And I would approach it in two steps for readability:

```
$scope.clearComplete = function() {

  //push completed tasks to completedTasks
  $scope.taskList.forEach(function(t) {
    if(t.complete) {
      $scope.completedTasks.push(t.foo);
    }
  });

  //then filter the task list
  $scope.taskList = $scope.taskList.filter(function(t) {
    return !t.complete;
  });

  console.log($scope.completedTasks);
  return $scope.taskList;
};
```

Comment: Wow, I feel silly. I was trying some solutions with forEach but just couldn't make it work. Sometimes it just takes a fresh eye. Thanks so much!

Comment: yes it will work obviously, but once forEach and then again filter is not required at all, once foreach is enough, we can do the filter inside.

Comment: I agree, this function is not the best for performance, but it does a good job at illustrating the problem and possible solutions. It can be easily refactored to improve performance

Answer (score 2):

first of all if you are doing `taskList.splic` then loop backwards. 
otherwise you can do like this:

```
var incompleteTasks = [];
$scope.tasks.forEach(function(task){
    if(task.complete) {
        $scope.completedTasks.push(task.foo);
    } else {
        incompleteTasks.push(task);
    }
});
$scope.tasks = incompleteTasks;
```

so, you will iterating exactly once to your array, and make it happen with very cleaner approach.